# Qt TableWidget - The image that appears when you click the cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qstyleditemdelegate

I use a QTableWidget with two columns.
The first column display images. The second column display text.
I'm calling `QBrush::setTexture` on the first column, not the `setIcon` function.

I want the first column images to change when I click on their cell but there is a problem with the image that appears when I click the cell.

This is the image that I expect:
[image: This is the image that I expect]

This is the image that I get:
[image: This is the image that I get]

Here is the code

.h file

```
class KcBackgroundDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate { public:
explicit KcBackgroundDelegate(QObject *parent = 0)
       : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
   {

   }

   void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
              const QModelIndex &index) const
   {

       QVariant background = index.data(Qt::BackgroundRole);
        if (background.canConvert<QBrush>())
           painter->fillRect(option.rect, background.value<QBrush>());

        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

       if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
       {
           if(index.column() == 0 )
           {
               painter->save();
               painter->fillRect(option.rect,QBrush(QPixmap(":/Resources/img/System/setting_aircraft_on_bt.png")));
               painter->restore();
           }
       }

       if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
       {
           if(index.column() == 0)
           {
               painter->save();
               painter->fillRect(option.rect,QBrush(QPixmap(":/Resources/img/System/setting_aircraft_click_bt.png")));
               painter->restore();
           }
       }
   }
};
```

.cpp file

```
ui->TW_AIRCRAFT_TYPE->setItemDelegateForColumn(0,new KcBackgroundDelegate(this));
ui->TW_AIRCRAFT_TYPE->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->TW_AIRCRAFT_TYPE->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->TW_AIRCRAFT_TYPE->installEventFilter(this);
ui->TW_AIRCRAFT_TYPE->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

It seems there is a problem with the delegate but I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me.

Comment: Why do you use `fillRect` with a brush created from the image, instead of just using `drawImage`? When a patterned brush is created from an image, I'm not sure if there are guaranties about the alignment of the pattern.

Comment: @KarstenKoop I didn't know because I do not use a lot of QPainter.
I'll try. Thanks.